# Switching Cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, vectors, polar-coordinates

Vectorfield $F(x,y)=-yi+4xj$, expres this vectorfield in vectors **r** and **$\theta$**. With $\hat{r}=\cos(\theta)i+\sin(\theta)j$ and $\hat{\theta}=-\sin(\theta)i+\cos(\theta)j$.

So I wrote $F(x,y)$ in polar coordinates, which gives $r(-\sin(\theta)i+4\cos(\theta)j)$, I don't know how to write this as $\hat{r}$ and $\hat{\theta}$ because of that 4 in front of the cosine.

Comment: You want to find expressions for the unit vectors $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$ in terms of the unit vectors $\hat{r}$ and $\hat{\theta}$.  Then, substitute these expression into your expression for $F(x,y)$.  You will come out with something like $f(r,\lambda) \hat{r} + g(r,\lambda) \hat{\theta}$, where $f$ and $g$ are some functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you wrote:

$$ \hat{r} = \cos \theta \hat{i} + \sin \theta \hat{j} $$
$$ \hat{\theta} = -\sin \theta \hat{i} + \cos \theta \hat{j} $$

One can conclude (by projecting, or by just solving these equations) that:

$$ \hat{i} = \cos \theta \hat{r} - \sin \theta \hat{\theta} $$
$$ \hat{j} = \sin \theta \hat{r} + \cos \theta \hat{\theta} $$

Meaning that

$$F(r,\theta)=-r\sin \theta \hat{i} + 4r\cos \theta \hat{j} = $$
$$(-r\sin \theta \cos \theta + 4r \cos \theta \sin \theta)\hat{r} + (r\sin^2{\theta} + 4r \cos^2 {\theta})\hat{\theta} =  $$
$$ \frac{3}{2} r \sin (2\theta) \hat{r}  + r(3\cos^2 \theta +1)\hat{\theta}$$